# Delete a table from mongodb database

Tags: mongodb, command, putty

I'm really new to mongodb. I want to see data in one of my table in mongodb database. I tried using  `db.table_name.remove` `db.table_name.drop` but nothing is working. also the response is pretty weird.

```
function () {
if (arguments.length > 0) {
    throw "drop takes no argument";
}
this.resetIndexCache();
var ret = this._db.runCommand({drop:this.getName()});
if (!ret.ok) {
    if (ret.errmsg == "ns not found") {
        return false;
    }
    throw "drop failed: " + tojson(ret);
}
return true;
}
```

So please tell me the commands to remove table completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, use **()** after drop and remove. The response(result) should be **true** or **false**. For more information see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Overview+-+The+MongoDB+Interactive+Shell